# Compare dataframe rows to different values and extract list of true

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, apply, lapply

I am writing a Shiny app in R, and for part of my code, I need to identify all the elements of a dataframe that exceed a certain level. The trick is, the threshold is different for each row. The end goal is to have a list where element [[1]] is a two column dataframe, with the first column being the names (taken from the original column names) and the second column being the values that did (or did not, either way) pass the boolean test.

Here is a reproducible starting point:

```
set.seed(20)
rows = 400
cols = 300
df <- data.frame(matrix(runif(rows*cols), nrow = rows), row.names = NULL)
colnames(df) <- paste0('col', 1:cols)
compare <- runif(rows)
```

df is the original data, compare is the vector of values to which each row should be compared.
I have written a working code block that does what I want, but it runs rather slow, which is a nuisance for my Shiny app. It took me much longer to arrive at this solution than I expected, but I know I am not always the most efficient programmer, especially when it comes to apply loops in R, so I want to know if there is a faster/more efficient way to do this.

My current solution:

```
res <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x){
  currRow <- df[x,]
  tf <- currRow >= compare[x]
  ret2 <- data.frame(names(currRow)[tf], currRow[tf], row.names = NULL)
  colnames(ret2) <- c('Name', 'Value')
  ret2 <- ret2[complete.cases(ret2),]
  ret2 <- ret2[order(-ret2$Value),]
  return(ret2)
})
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all of the code in `lapply` could be vectorized by using matrix operations instead, yielding a ~10x increase in performance for your example data. The key thing to notice is that you can do all the comparisons with a single `sweep` to get the booleans; the rest is just wrangling the result into a list of data frames while making sure each original row gets an element in the list (even if no columns pass the test):

```r
f2 <- function() {
  x <- as.matrix(df)
  bool <- sweep(x, 1, compare, ">=")

  res <- data.frame(
    row   = as.vector(row(x)),
    Name  = colnames(x)[col(x)],
    Value = as.vector(x),
    pass  = as.vector(bool)
  )

  res <- res[order(-res$Value), ]

  lapply(split(res, res$row), function(x) {
    x <- x[complete.cases(x), ]
    x[x$pass, c("Name", "Value")]
  })
}

system.time(res1 <- f1()) # original
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    3.17    0.02    3.18
system.time(res2 <- f2())
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.27    0.01    0.28
all.equal(res1, res2, check.attributes = FALSE)
#> [1] TRUE
```

And here's the setup again:

```r
set.seed(20)
rows <- 400
cols <- 300

df <- data.frame(matrix(runif(rows * cols), nrow = rows), row.names = NULL)
colnames(df) <- paste0('col', 1:cols)
compare <- runif(rows)

f1 <- function() {
  lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x){
    currRow <- df[x,]
    tf <- currRow >= compare[x]
    ret2 <- data.frame(names(currRow)[tf], currRow[tf], row.names = NULL)
    colnames(ret2) <- c('Name', 'Value')
    ret2 <- ret2[complete.cases(ret2),]
    ret2 <- ret2[order(-ret2$Value),]
    return(ret2)
  })
}
```

Created on 2018-03-17 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you very much! One quick question: is using "sweep" necessary/better? It seems like I can get the same boolean matrix just using: x >= compare
and relying on R's fortification to give me the desired results

Comment: Ah, yeah you're absolutely right, that works fine, too. However, I generally try to avoid solutions that rely on vector recycling though, because if it turns out the lenghts are incompatible (or worse yet compatible in the wrong way) it's often a source for hard-to-diagnose bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special here, just taking here advantage of `data.table` super fast ordering and indexing.

This should be faster.

```
# Using apply (this is vectorized)
pes <- apply(df, 1, function(x){

    for(i in seq(compare))
    {
        # get indexes where the condition satisfies
        ix <- which(x >= compare[i])

        # get values
        val <- x[ix]

        # get column names
        nam <- names(x)[ix]

        # store above data
        df <- data.table(Name = nam, Value = val)
        df <- df[order(-Value)]
        df <- df[complete.cases(df)]
        return(df)
    }
})
```

Comment: It seems that you are only ever comparing the rows against the first element in `compare`, as you always return on the first iteration in the loop?